# Adding To An Existing Irrevocable Trust

Tags: united-states, trusts

In the USA, once an irrevocable trust has been set up and funded, can the donor add additional funds at a later date?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. 
20+ years ago I set one up so my wife and I could give our minor daughter the annual limit and get this money out of our name. Irrevocable, with an intention of annual deposits. Now, it’s a source of funds for her college tuition.